# WP8 upload image on server using multipart/form-data, getting error

Tags: windows-phone-8, multipartform-data, dotnet-httpclient

Following code tries to upload image to server using *multipart/form-data*:

```
public async void PostRequest(Stream photoStream, string lomail, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            photoStream.Position = 0;
            using (MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                content.Add(new StringContent(lomail), "lomail");
                content.Add(new StreamContent(photoStream), "photo", fileName);

                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("post");
                });

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(LoUrl, content);
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                     MessageBox.Show(response.ToString());
                });

                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("finish");
                });
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("post request: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

But there's HTTP error: (status code 404, Http.StramContent, Header: Content-length=0)

How do this correctly?

Comment: Can you please explain a) what you are trying to do, b) what have you tried, and c) what problems you are facing?  You haven't actually asked anything :)

Comment: Sorry! It's my first question on stackowerflow. I'm trying to upload image to server, but i have error with status code 404.

Comment: No problem, welcome to StackOverflow.  Are you confident that you're posting to the correct URL?  Is the server working, i.e. can you upload manually to the same URL?

Comment: I think URL is correct. "http://lomobil.com/handler/upload/"

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution.

```
public async void PostRequest(Stream photoStream, string lomail, string fileName)
       {
           try
           {
               using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
               {
                   client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                   photoStream.Position = 0;
                   using (MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                   {
                       content.Add(new StringContent(lomail), "lomail");
                       content.Add(new StreamContent(photoStream), "photo", fileName);
                       //var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(ImageData);
                       //imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");

                       //content.Add(imageContent, "photo", "image.jpg");
                       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                       {
                           MessageBox.Show("post");
                       });

                       HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(LoUrl, content);
                       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                       {
                            MessageBox.Show(response.ToString());
                       });

                       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                       {
                           MessageBox.Show("finish");
                       });
                   }
               }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("post request: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: my api return json,how to get json response from it.thanks in advance

Comment: This is not the right place to ask this. First of all, you should consider creating a new question, but it seems like the answer will already be given somewhere, so take a look at bing (yes!) or google.

Comment: @koch_kir You could probably accept this answer (that checkmark at the upper left corner of the answer), that's the Stack Overflow way to mark the problem "solved". And it's fine and good to accept your own answer if you know it works and when there's no better answer from somebody else.